# How to convert Go struct to C struct?

Tags: go, hash, struct, cgo

I want to use cgo. On the C side I have struct containing 32 bytes.

```
struct hash {
    uint8_t bytes[32];
};
```

On the Go size I have very similar type.

```
type Hash [32]bytes
```

I would like to call a C function `void f(struct hash)` with an instance of `Hash` type. If possible I would also like to avoid a copy of the value.

Simple assignment `Chash C.struct_hash := hash` does not work:

> cannot use hash (type Hash) as type C.struct_hash in assignment

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `unsafe` package to cast the data. The Go compiler can no longer check the types here, so it's up to you to ensure that the size and type of everything is identical between `C.struct_hash` and `Hash`.

```
Chash := *(*C.struct_hash)(unsafe.Pointer(&hash))
```

Answer (score 1):

consider the align in c 
you can not simply do the cast.
the best way should be  assign  value 1 by 1 from c to go or go to c.
But this process is painful is the struct is large and struct contain struct